# How to add Location Toggle settings in Windows Phone 8 app?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I recently uploaded a Windows Phone 8 app but I got a message saying **Certification Failed** with the below error.

**10.5 Location Services Toggle**

`Apps that receive device location must provide settings that allow the user to enable and disable the app's access to and use of location from the Location Service API. For Windows Phone apps, these settings must be provided in-app.`

I got this error due to change in Policy of Windows Phone Apps. Can anyone suggest how can I add such location Settings in my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the app first starts, show a popup to the user asking if they want to allow the app to use their location, telling them they can change it anytime on a settings page. Then also create the settings page with the toggle.

Comment: I have the exact same problem, and obviously this is the solution, yes. But how to disable this location through an in-app toggle with c#? Any ideas, because I cannot find a suitable sample in the Internet?

Comment: You can not enabled or disable location services system-wide. The idea is to have a settings in your app and only use the location services if it is set